# Can I install windows 10 on my desktop using recovery drive I created on laptop?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-10-v1909

I would like to do this because I don't have enough data to download windows 10 using **create windows 10 installation media** directly on my desktop.

So I was thinking that I create a recovery drive of my laptop's windows 10 and then install it on my desktop... Would this work?

Comment: This will not work. The recovery drive is only housing the recovery tools, not the actual windows install.

Comment: No you cannot transfer the OS to different hardware, the licence will not allow activation if you do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows embeds its license key in the computer's ACPI tables (laptop hardware, *not* the HDD).

You can:

Install Windows 10 from boot media (USB) using their [freely available ISO](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10ISO) to the HDD - this <strike>will</strike> may wipe the HDD so beware. I *believe* Windows will pick up the previous license key but I would have it handy to enter - pull it from the current Windows version and write it down first. Backup any existing user data on external storage first.

Comment: The Windows installer _will not_ wipe data by default if the PC had a previous version of Windows on it - it will move all directories and files from the root of the previous system partition to `C:\Windows.old`.  A user can choose to format the system partition, but it requires user intervention to do so.

Comment: Thanks. Probably better for the OP to install to empty HDD since space is an issue.